# WooCommerce order received url link shortcode displays nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, xcode, woocommerce, shortcode

I am needing help on this custom code I have created. The purpose of this shortcode is to display a clickable link to the customers order received page on the order received email. I want the link to be accessible for all customers including those that do not have an account. The order status when order is placed is on-hold if that helps.

```html
function emailurlorder()
 {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if ( $order ) {
   $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
          return;
          {
$checkout_order_received_url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
if ($order_checkout_order_received_url) {
return $order_checkout_order_received_url;
}
ob_start();
$pay_link = $checkout_order_received_url;
$payment_text = __('Click here to pay','text_domain');
    
echo  '<a href="' . $pay_link . '">' . $payment_text . '</a>';

$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $contents; '<a href="' . $pay_link . '">' . $payment_text . '</a>';
}
        }
}
add_shortcode('orderlink','emailurlorder');
```

What it is suppose to do is display a clickable link labeled as "Click here to pay" and the url is my websites order received page for that specific order.
Problem- Shortcode displays absolutely nothing not even the shortcode text ([orderlink]).

Comment: You need to pass the `$order_id` to the shortcode

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Are you able to edit the code I have created so that it would work? I’m not very knowledgeable on all this.